# Running docker without sudo on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I attempted to set up Docker so that I do not have to type `sudo` before using it.

The steps that I took:

1. I started with creating a docker group with `sudo groupadd docker`;
2. I added my current user to the "docker" group with `sudo gpasswd -a ${USER} docker`;
3. I restarted docker with `sudo service docker restart`;
4. I closed and opened the terminal to start a new session.

After running `docker run hello-world`, I receive this output:

> FATA[0000] Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.17/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: permission denied. Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?

One thing that puzzles (and might give a hint about why I cannot run docker without sudo) is the output of:

`$ groups`: is:

> ltarasiewicz adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare

(no "docker" group)

The output of `$ groups ltarasiewicz`:

> ltarasiewicz adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare docker

("docker" is one of the groups)

What might be the reason for the fact that I still cannot use Docker withou `sudo` after adding my current user to the "docker" group?

Comment: Beware that running Docker without sudo is dangerous, make sure to understand the associated security risks. See https://medium.com/@msuixo/linux-users-running-docker-without-sudo-is-dangerous-3e5c5654abea

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Group changes don't take effect immediately in the currently logged in session.  Your options include:

1. Log out then log back in
2. Start a new login session (for bash this is with the `bash -l` command)

Comment: Indeed, the solution is to log out from the current session and then log in again. I was wrongly convinced that closing and opening the terminal will do the job of applying the group changes.

Comment: Running the 'id' command should show 'docker' in the groups list

Answer (score 22):

Run the following command at the end to apply group settings:

```
newgrp docker
```

Answer (score 6):

Closing terminal or logging out wasn't enough in my case, I had to do a complete reboot.

Comment: And even sudo service docker restart did not work. Complete restart only!

Comment: Done! Thanks! I'm wondering what is restarted at reboot which didn't restarted after all of the manipulation described above?

Comment: IIRC I was wondering that too...