# How to fix docker: Got permission denied issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I installed Docker in my machine where I have Ubuntu OS.
When I run:

```bash
sudo docker run hello-world
```

All is ok, but I want to hide the `sudo` command to make the command shorter.
If I write the command without `sudo`

```bash
docker run hello-world
```

That displays the following:

```
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.35/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied. See 'docker run --help'.
```

The same happens when I try to run:

```bash
docker-compose up
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running docker without sudo on Ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29199884/running-docker-without-sudo-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

Comment: adder user in docker group and assign permission

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker.sock permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568172/docker-sock-permission-denied)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854463/docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socke)

Comment: Read docker official doc :  https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/ for this problem.

Comment: This was helpful for me - "For anyone stumbling across this issue on mac...
https://github.com/docker/buildx/issues/415#issuecomment-781240796"

Comment: Run all docker commands with sudo.

Comment: Firstly, you should check if docker is set up properly in linux distro/wsl. For this, run "docker ps" in the environment. My guess is that this should also give the same error. Now run "docker run --rm -it --gpus=all nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample:nbody nbody -gpu -benchmark". 
That should resolve the issue. Try running "docker ps" once again to verify.

Answer (score 2162, accepted):

If you want to run docker as non-root user then you need to add it to the docker group.

1. Create the docker group if it does not exist

```bash
$ sudo groupadd docker
```

2. Add your user to the docker group.

```bash
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

3. Log in to the new `docker` group (to avoid having to log out / log in again; but if not enough, try to reboot):

```bash
$ newgrp docker
```

4. Check if docker can be run without root

```bash
$ docker run hello-world
```

Reboot if still got error

```bash
$ reboot
```

**Warning**

> The docker group grants privileges equivalent to the root user. For details on how this impacts security in your system, see [Docker Daemon Attack Surface.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface).

Taken from the docker official documentation:
[manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user)

Comment: @heez a reboot may not have been required, restarting docker was enough for me.

`sudo systemctl restart docker`

Comment: It worked for me without reboot, but I had to restart docker and switch user to my same user to refresh the login.  'sudo systemctl restart docker' then 'su - {your username}'

Comment: I have this problem in windows any idea how can I fix it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55924416/docker-permission-denied-in-windows

Comment: After step 2, I had to perform `systemctl start docker` to make it work

Comment: @heez: `su - $USER` can be used to avoid the log out / log in as per [this question](https://superuser.com/a/354475/173159).

Comment: If you are running Ubuntu 18 and installed docker via snap, you can restart docker via snap which should eliminate the need for a system restart. `$sudo snap restart docker`

Comment: If running in a VM Machine, you may need to restart the machine: https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user

Comment: also `docker.help` command suggest do `newgrp docker`, after this I do not need docker service to be restarted and computer reboot, changes take efferct after it

Comment: It seems that the latest version already has a group, so we just need to add user

Comment: there is an experimental rootless mode:https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/

Comment: Hello @mkb when I try to run `docker build .` I got same error so I tried like this way `sudo docker build .` it worked is it a wrong way ?

Comment: Why doesn't `sudo apt-get install docker` take care of this for us?

Comment: In my case changing the owner of the docker.sock file from root to the user trying to run it worked for me. just ran this command: `sudo chown $(whoami) /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: This issue happened as I installed docker as root user and docker-compose with user permission

Comment: This helped me `sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: ```newgrp docker``` requests a Password which I haven't set/don't have. It doesn't accept no password either.

Comment: thanks, worked! unfortunately i ran the docker hello-world example and it overwrote my whole setup, don't know why. but i got it working in the end

Answer (score 836):

After an upgrade I got the permission denied.
Doing the steps of 'mkb' [post install steps](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user) don't have change anything because my user was already in the 'docker' group; I retry-it twice any way without success.

After an search hour this following solution finaly worked :

```bash
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Solution came from [Olshansk](https://github.com/jgsqware/clairctl/issues/60).

Look like the upgrade have recreate the socket without enough permission for the 'docker' group.

#### Problems

This hard *chmod* open security hole and after each reboot, this error start again and again and you have to re-execute the above command each time.  I want a solution once and for all. For that you have two problems :

- 1 ) **Problem with *`SystemD`*** : The socket will be create only with owner 'root' and group 'root'.

  You can check this first problem with this command :

  ```bash
  ls -l /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket
  ```

  If every this is good, you should see '`root/docker`' not '`root/root`'.
- 2 ) **Problem with *graphical Login*** : https://superuser.com/questions/1348196/why-my-linux-account-only-belongs-to-one-group

  You can check this second problem with this command :

  ```bash
  groups
  ```

  If everything is correct you should see the *docker* group in the list.
  If not try the command

  ```bash
  sudo su $USER -c groups
  ```

  if you see then the *docker* group it is because of the bug.

### Solutions

If you manage to to get a workaround for the graphical login, this should do the job :

```bash
sudo chgrp docker /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket
sudo chmod g+w /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket
```

But If you can't manage this bug, a not so bad solution could be this :

```bash
sudo chgrp $USER /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket
sudo chmod g+w /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket
```

This work because you are in a graphical environnement and probably the only user on your computer.
In both case you need a reboot (or `sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`)

Comment: if docker was installed as per doc on https://docs.docker.com/install/  then you never need to deal with any such commands

Comment: @Scott Stensland I have install docker many time 'as per doc'. I think the problem come from a bad interaction with another unidentified package.

Comment: In docker-in-docker, I was incorrectly mounting /var/run/docker.sock from the host without the `:ro` on the end... as soon as I added that I was good to go

Comment: I was on `centos` with user `centos`, `sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock` perfectly worked.

Comment: I use ubuntu 18 on EC2 - AWS and prefectly worked. All the others (sudo usermod -aG docker $ USER and other stuff) did not work

Comment: This is the fix for my raspberry pi 3b+

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I have recently installed the latest ubuntu and I-m having LOTS of problems using Py3.7, pip, docker-compose, etc. Why are things still so complicated?

Comment: Thanks, it fixed in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.
restating and adding to groud didn't

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Thanks. I was struggling with this issue and no other method seemed to work. Used this command and worked just fine.

Comment: On my setup, normal terminal application on Ubuntu was giving access denied error while terminator was working fine. I have no idea why the issue was happening but it's fixed now since essentially everyone has access to the docker socket.

Comment: I didnot have to restart my Ubuntu, however this command did the job for me. Now, I can do docker run hello-world without sudo

Comment: I was connected to vm from windows 10 and was getting the same error of authentication. It was solved by changing the permission `sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`.
Thanks @Galigator !!

Comment: @Ady This was the 'do not use solution', the true solution is at the end of the post.

Comment: Hi, should the line `sudo chgrp $USER /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket` really be `sudo chown $USER /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket`? The User is not a group, right?
And then `sudo chmod g+w /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket` is probably `sudo chmod u+w /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket`...

Comment: @zaphod, maybe $USER is not the group, but on many distribution a group with the name of the user is create when installing the system.

Comment: I found that using `sudo chmod o+wr /var/run/docker.sock` works much better as opposed to 666. Not sure why, but on my system it will stop working after a while.

Comment: @Olshansk here. Appreciate the shoutout :)

Comment: @Galigator: group of /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket is expected to be root.

Comment: @Shantanu No, see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.socket.html  , depending of your configuration in /lib/systemd/system/docker.service you can have group/user != root, If nothing is specified and an no-root user run the process then by default (no group/users specified) it will be not root.

Comment: Hi @Galigator: See CIS Docker Benchmark 1.3.1 page 95 https://workbench.cisecurity.org/files/3353 : 

"You should verify that the docker.socket file ownership and group ownership are correctly set to root." 

"The docker.socket file contains sensitive parameters that may alter the behavior of the Docker remote API. For this reason, it should be owned and group owned by root in order to ensure that it is not modified by less privileged users."

Comment: @Shantanu this resource is private and so should be draft. Also it look like a recommendation for server deployment not end user desktop.

Answer (score 70):

1. Add current user to `docker` group

```bash
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

2. Change the permissions of docker socket to be able to connect
   to the docker daemon `/var/run/docker.sock`

```bash
sudo chmod 660 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: this solution worked for me for this problem docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.

Comment: Absolutely not! Never give permission to the world!  Permission on the docker socket should be 660, and as long as your user is in the `docker` group, you'll be fine.

Comment: @Auspex, this was 4 years ago! please feel free to update the solution and I will be more than happy to update it :)

Comment: I'm not updating it. There are numerous correct answers here. I know it was four years ago, but you are recommending that people open up their entire systems to hackers, and that's worth a revival. You clearly don't have a clue just how dangerous making the docker socket world writable is.

Answer (score 55):

1. Add docker group

```bash
$ sudo groupadd docker
```

2. Add your current user to docker group

```bash
$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

3. Switch session to docker group

```bash
$ newgrp - docker
```

4. Run an example to test

```bash
$ docker run hello-world
```

Comment: The `newgrp` command prompted for a password and didn't accept my user password. Instead `su - $USER` worked to avoid logging out/in.

Answer (score 41):

I solve this error with the command :

```bash
$ sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: i am using ubuntu 18.04 lts server, i used this command, rebootet, but still got error :(

Comment: You will always need to run it again every time you boot your machine, If you want it to run automatically on startup, follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69269302/14043328

Comment: Absolutely not! Never give permission to the world!  Permission on the docker socket should be 660, and as long as your user is in the `docker` group, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 33):

If creating a docker group and adding your user to it doesn't work (the best solution, described in the previous answers), then this one is the second best alternative:

```bash
sudo chown $USER /var/run/docker.sock
```

What it does is changing the ownership of the `docker.sock` file to your user.

*Note: It's a really bad practice to use `chmod 666`, because it gives permissions to practically everyone to access and modify the `docker.sock` file.*

Answer (score 23):

It only requires the changes in permission of sock file.

```bash
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

this will work definitely.

Comment: this will open a security hole and need to be redo after each reboot.

Comment: Absolutely not! Never give permission to the world!  Permission on the docker socket should be 660, and as long as your user is in the `docker` group, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 15):

#### Fix Docker Issue: (Permission denied)

- Create the docker group if it does not exist: `sudo groupadd docker`
- See number of super users in the available system: `grep -Po '^sudo.+:\K.*$' /etc/group`
- Export the user in linux command shell: `export USER=demoUser`
- Add user to the docker group: `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`
- Run the following command/ Login or logout: `newgrp docker`
- Check if docker runs ok or not: `docker run hello-world`
- Reboot if you still get an error: `reboot`

#### If it does not work, run this command:

`sudo chmod 660 /var/run/docker.sock`

Comment: Blindly `777` shouldn't be used

Comment: @Akshay Hedge Why?  I used the `777` option and it worked

Comment: @PurushothamanSrikanth `777` means that anyone can do anything with those files

Comment: Don't use `777`!  Use `660` or `640`

Comment: `660` doesn't work. For me it was set per default.

Comment: if 660 didn't work, you might have needed `sudo chgrp docker /var/run/docker.sock` but please stop blindly perpetuating the insane concept of giving docker access to the world. It's not as @AkshayHegde said that anyone can do anything to "those files", it's that anyone can do anything **to your entire system** once they have control of the docker socket

Answer (score 14):

We always forget about `ACLs` . See [`setfacl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl).

```bash
sudo setfacl -m user:$USER:rw /var/run/docker.sock`**
```

Comment: in case its complaining that facl not found, install with `sudo apt install acl`

Comment: I'm getting "setfacl: Option -m: Invalid argument near character 6" this error.

Comment: .sock is a socket file, these are temporary files and you'd have to run the same command every time.  Setting default in the parent folder would work, but this is /var/run, and we don't want non-privileged users to have rw access over every file in /var/run.

Answer (score 13):

You can always try `Manage Docker as a non-root user` paragraph in the https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/ docs.

After doing this also if the problem persists then you can run the following command to solve it:

```bash
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Making the docker socket readable or writable to everyone (with `chmod 666`) is a security disaster... This should never be recommended.

Comment: @AaylaSecura Thanks for giving us heads up but could you also please briefly explain why readable or writable sockets are disaster?

Comment: Anyone who can talk to the docker socket is effectively `root` on the host system! See this for example: https://fosterelli.co/privilege-escalation-via-docker and many other resources on docker privilege escalation. Making the socket world writable effectively gives all UNIX users `root` privileges.

Comment: Do not assign `666` permissions. `660` or `640` should be more than enough.

Comment: Absolutely not! Never give permission to the world!  Permission on the docker socket should be 660, and as long as your user is in the `docker` group, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 11):

To fix that issue, I searched where is my docker and docker-compose installed. In my case, `docker` was installed in `/usr/bin/docker` and `docker-compose` was installed in `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose` path. Then, I write this in my terminal:

To docker:

```bash
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker
```

To `docker-compose`:

```bash
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Now I don't need write in my commands docker the word `sudo`

/***********************************************************************/

ERRATA:

The best solution of this issue was commented by @mkasberg. I quote comment:

`That might work, you might run into issues down the road. Also, it's a security vulnerability. You'd be better off just adding yourself to the docker group, as the docs say. sudo groupadd docker, sudo usermod -aG docker $USER.`
`Docs:` https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/

Comment: That might work, you might run into issues down the road. Also, it's a security vulnerability. You'd be better off just adding yourself to the `docker` group, as the docs say. `sudo groupadd docker`, `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`.

Comment: Hey @mkasberg! Thanks for your comment! I maked a errata to cited your solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: this does not work

Comment: I had to also run `newgrp docker` after the usermod command, otherwise it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/images/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

```bash
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

This fix my problem.

Comment: Absolutely not! Never give permission to the world!  Permission on the docker socket should be 660, and as long as your user is in the `docker` group, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 8):

## ubuntu 21.04 systemd socket ownership

Let me preface, this was a perfectly suitable solution for me during  local development and I got here searching for `ubuntu docker permission error` so i'll just leave this here.

I didn't own the unix socket, so I chowned it.

```bash
sudo chown $(whoami):$(whoami) /var/run/docker.sock
```

Another, more permanent solution for your dev environment, is to modify the user ownership of the unix socket creation. This will give your user the ownership, so it'll stick between restarts:

```bash
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/docker.socket
```

docker.socket:

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Socket for the API

[Socket]
ListenStream=/var/run/docker.sock
SocketMode=0660
SocketUser=YOUR_USERNAME_HERE
SocketGroup=docker

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Comment: A really different solution than all others.

Comment: Doesn't work, not even after `sudo systemctl restart docker`.

Comment: I really don't think setting your user as the socket owner is the right answer, but upvoted because this seems to be the only answer that actually looks in the right place.

Answer (score 4):

use this command

```bash
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

then restart your computer this worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Seriously guys. Do not add Docker in your groups or modify the socket posix (without a hardening SELinux), it's a simple way to make a root privesc. Just add an alias in your `.bashrc`. It's simpler and safer as: `alias dc='sudo docker'`.

Comment: Maybe you could speak about : https://podman.io/ . But running in root seem to be  usecase for developers.

Answer (score 4):

This work for me:

Get inside the container and modify the file's ACL

```bash
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
sudo setfacl --modify user:$USER:rw /var/run/docker.sock
```

It's a better solution than use chmod.

Comment: .sock files are socket files and temporary by nature.  You'd have to set this every time docker starts.

Answer (score 3):

lightdm and kwallet ship with a bug that seems to not pass the supplementary groups at login. To solve this, I also, beside `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`, had to comment out

```
auth optional pam_kwallet.so
auth optional pam_kwallet5.so
```

to

```
#auth optional pam_kwallet.so
#auth optional pam_kwallet5.so
```

in `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` **before rebooting**, for the docker-group to actually have effect.

bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/1781418 and here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1581495

Answer (score 3):

you can follow these steps and this will work for you:

1. create a docker group  `sudo groupadd docker`
2. add your user to this group `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`
3. list the groups to make sure that docker group created successfully by running this command `groups`
4. run the following command also to change the session for docker group `newgrp docker`
5. change the group ownership for file docker.sock`sudo chown root:docker /var/run/docker.sock`
6. change the ownership for .docker directory `sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" /home/"$USER"/.docker -R`
7. finally `sudo chmod g+rwx "$HOME/.docker" -R`

After that test you can run `docker ps -a`

Comment: I wanted an answer that doesn't require rebooting. This was the only answer that provided that. The "trick" is to `chown` the docker.sock file.

Answer (score 2):

Rebooting the machine worked for me.

```bash
$ reboot
```

Comment: this is worst solution since it will not work and restart the system :(

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem as well, but where the container I wanted to create needed to mount /var/run/docker.sock as a volume (Portainer Agent), while running it all under a different namespace. Normally a container does not care about which namespace it is started in -- that is sort of the point -- but since access was made from a different namespace, this had to be circumvented.

Adding `--userns=host` to the run command for the container enabled it to use the attain the correct permissions.

Quite a specific use case, but after more research hours than I want to admit I just thought I should share it with the world if someone else ends up in this situation :)

Answer (score 1):

The Docker daemon binds to a Unix socket instead of a TCP port.
By default that Unix socket is owned by the user **root** and other users can only access it using **sudo**. The Docker daemon always runs as the root user.

If you don’t want to preface the docker command with sudo, create a Unix group called docker and add users to it. When the Docker daemon starts, it creates a Unix socket accessible by members of the docker group.

To create the docker group and add your user:

1. Create the docker group

   ```bash
   sudo groupadd docker
   ```
2. Add your user to the docker group

   ```bash
   sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
   ```
3. Log out and log back in so that your group membership is re-evaluated.

   If testing on a virtual machine, it may be necessary to restart the virtual machine for changes to take effect.

   On a desktop Linux environment such as X Windows, log out of your session completely and then log back in.

   On Linux, you can also run the following command to activate the changes to groups:

   ```bash
   newgrp docker
   ```
4. Verify that you can run docker commands without sudo. The below command downloads a test image and runs it in a container. When the container runs, it prints an informational message and exits

   ```bash
   docker run hello-world
   ```

If you initially ran Docker CLI commands using sudo before adding your user to the docker group, you may see the following error, which indicates that your **~/.docker/** directory was created with incorrect permissions due to the sudo commands.

```
WARNING: Error loading config file: /home/user/.docker/config.json -
stat /home/user/.docker/config.json: permission denied
```

To fix this problem, either **remove the ~/.docker/** directory (it is recreated automatically, but any custom settings are lost), or change its ownership and permissions using the following commands:

```bash
sudo chown "$USER":"$USER" /home/"$USER"/.docker -R

sudo chmod g+rwx "$HOME/.docker" -R
```

All other post installation steps for docker on linux can be found here https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Answer (score 1):

i try this commend with `sudo` commend and it was ok.`sudo docker pull hello-world` or `sudo docker run hello-world`

Comment: That will always work. The OP was having trouble doing it without `sudo` -- which _should_ work as long as you're in the `docker` group

Answer (score 1):

**Adding answer here for future reference:**
(This is the cause and what solved it for my use case)

This happens when your Unix user account lacks permission to interact with the socket that exposes the Docker API. Adding yourself to the docker group is the best practice way to resolve this problem:

`$ sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`

You'll need to open a new shell window or logout and back in again for this change to take effect.

[Source](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=458f4bcdf872cdcfJmltdHM9MTY5Mzk1ODQwMCZpZ3VpZD0wZmNhMWVjNC03NzJlLTYyMGUtMDZiMi0wYzM3NzY0NTYzY2QmaW5zaWQ9NTUxMg&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=0fca1ec4-772e-620e-06b2-0c37764563cd&psq=permission%20denied%20while%20trying%20to%20connect%20to%20the%20Docker%20daemon%20socket%20at%20unix%3A%2F%2F%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock%3A%20Post%20%22http%3A%2F%2F%252Fvar%252Frun%252Fdocker.sock%2Fv1.24%2Fauth%22%3A%20dial%20unix%20%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock%3A%20connect%3A%20permission%20denied&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuaG93dG9nZWVrLmNvbS9kZXZvcHMvaG93LXRvLXRyb3VibGVzaG9vdC1jYW5ub3QtY29ubmVjdC10by10aGUtZG9ja2VyLWRhZW1vbi1lcnJvcnMvIzp-OnRleHQ9VGhpcyUyMGhhcHBlbnMlMjB3aGVuJTIweW91ciUyMFVuaXglMjB1c2VyJTIwYWNjb3VudCUyMGxhY2tzLGluJTIwYWdhaW4lMjBmb3IlMjB0aGlzJTIwY2hhbmdlJTIwdG8lMjB0YWtlJTIwZWZmZWN0Lg&ntb=1)

Answer (score 1):

You just need the check permissions for this file /var/run/docker.sock
it should be 666
**chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock**

Comment: Just add sudo to the above command

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely not the case the question was about, but as it is the first search result while googling the error message, I'll leave it here.

First of all, check if docker service is running using the following command:

`systemctl status docker.service`

If it is not running, try starting it:

`sudo systemctl start docker.service`

... and check the status again:

`systemctl status docker.service`

If it has not started, investigate the reason. Probably, you have modified a config file and made an error (like I did while modifying `/etc/docker/daemon.json`)

Answer (score 0):

In the Linux environment, after installing `docker` and `docker-compose` reboot is required for work docker better to avoid this issue

```bash
$ sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: Just installed docker on Ubuntu. Restarting didn't solve the "permission denied".

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the described methods and nothing helped to solve the problem. The solution was to use the --use-drivers parameter when running selenoid and selenoid-ui. Below is the full listing of my Dockerfile.

```
FROM selenoid/chrome
USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install docker.io
RUN curl -s https://aerokube.com/cm/bash | bash
RUN ./cm selenoid start --vnc --use-drivers
RUN ./cm selenoid-ui start --use-drivers
EXPOSE 4444 8080
CMD ["-conf", "/etc/selenoid/browsers.json", "-video-output-dir", "/opt/selenoid/video/"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the **process itself** (CI server agent) that was trying to run a docker command wasn't able to run it, but when I tried to run same command from within the same user it worked.

Restarting the daemon that runs CI server agent solved the problem.

The reason why command wasn't working from within agent before is because the agent was running before I installed docker and granted docker group permissions, and agent process used cached old permissions and was failing. Restarting the process dropped the cache and make things work out.

Answer (score 0):

**As a shortest answer for linux user ->**

**Simply try any command as super user with "sudo"**

Eg:- `sudo docker-compose up`

Answer (score 0):

If the user was already in the 'docker' group; try to give permission
to /var/run/docker.sock file
`sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`
it will work

Answer (score 0):

Docker already created a guide to [Run the Docker daemon as a non-root user (Rootless mode)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/).

> Rootless mode allows running the Docker daemon and containers as a non-root user to mitigate potential vulnerabilities in the daemon and the container runtime.

Answer (score -1):

After Docker Installation on Centos. While running below command I got below error.

```
[centos@aiops-dev-cassandra3 ~]$ docker run hello-world
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.soc k/v1.40/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Change Group and Permission for docker.socket

```bash
[centos@aiops-dev-cassandra3 ~]$ ls -l /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 197 Nov 13 07:25 /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket
[centos@aiops-dev-cassandra3 ~]$ sudo chgrp docker /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket
[centos@aiops-dev-cassandra3 ~]$ sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
[centos@aiops-dev-cassandra3 ~]$ ls -lrth /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw-rw-. 1 root docker 0 Nov 20 11:59 /var/run/docker.sock
[centos@aiops-dev-cassandra3 ~]$
```

Verify by using below docker command

```
[centos@aiops-dev-cassandra3 ~]$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
1b930d010525: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:c3b4ada4687bbaa170745b3e4dd8ac3f194ca95b2d0518b417fb47e5879d9b5f
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

[centos@aiops-dev-cassandra3 ~]$
```

Comment: Absolutely not! Never give permission to the world! Permission on the docker socket should be 660, and as long as your user is in the docker group, you'll be fine.

Answer (score -1):

After you installed docker, created 'docker' group and added user to it, edit docker service unit file:

```bash
sudo nano /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service
```

Add two lines into the section [Service]:

```
SupplementaryGroups=docker    
ExecStartPost=/bin/chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Save the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Run and enable the Docker service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl enable docker
```

Comment: Almost right. Never give permission to the world! Permission on the docker socket should be 660, and as long as your user is in the docker group, you'll be fine.

Comment: what's the purpose of `SupplementaryGroups=docker` ?

Answer (score -1):

The **most straightforward solution** is to type

`sudo chmod 640 /var/run/docker.sock`
every time you boot your machine. However, this method defeats any system security that may be in place and opens up the Docker socket to everybody. If this is acceptable to you -e.g.: the only user of your machine- then use it.

Nevertheless, it will be required every time you boot your machine, you can make it run with booting by adding

```
start on startup
task
exec chmod 640 /var/run/docker.sock
```

to the `/etc/init/docker-chmod.conf` file.

Comment: `666` Is excessive permissions. `660` or  `640` should be more than enough

Comment: I updated it to `640`. Thanks for raising the concern.

Answer (score -1):

Below command helped me

## run this if linux

```bash
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: please explain what this does and how and why it solves the problem.

Comment: Never ever grant write permissions to "others" which is what the last 6 in your example is doing. Doing so on a socket of a running process is worse, but doing so on a container runtime process such as docker is worst of all. Have a group, grant access to that group, have your user join that group.

Answer (score -4):

```bash
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

this helped me while I was getting error even to log in to the docker.
But now this works completely fine in my system.

Comment: It is very insecure to use this method. Review the post-install instructions that was provided on the comments in the main question.

Answer (score -4):

Just open terminal and type this command

```bash
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: This defeats any system security that may be in place, and opens up the Docker socket to everybody.

Answer (score -7):

### A simple hack is to execute as a **"Super User"**.

To access the super user or root user, follow:

At *user@computer*:

```
$sudo su
```

After you enter your password, you'll be at *root@computer*:

```
$docker run hello-world
```