# Issues installing Docker on RHEL 7 Linux Server

Tags: linux, docker

I have been constantly running into this issue more and more lately, and finally need some assistance because I'm completely stuck.

I just got access to a RHEL EC2 Linux server and I am just simply trying to install Docker. This process has been extremely painful lately. Tons of 404 HTTP Not Found errors when trying to follow the processes mentioned online

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html, you can just simply run one of the following two commands:

- sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker
- sudo yum install docker

However, neither one of these comands work, as shown in the output below:

```
[root@d8de679d27f2454 myuser]# sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker
sudo: amazon-linux-extras: command not found
[root@d8de679d27f2454 myuser]# yum install docker
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, search-disabled-repos
No package docker available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@d8de679d27f2454 myuser]#
```

Here is a list of things I've tried to do :

***First Attempt*** (RE: [How to install docker on Amazon Linux2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53918841/how-to-install-docker-on-amazon-linux2))

The second answer proposed in that you can just run the following:

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum -y install docker
```

However, that doesn't work either, as shown in the output below:

```
[root@d8de679d27f2454 myuser]# yum update -y
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, search-disabled-repos
No packages marked for update
[root@d8de679d27f2454 myuser]# yum -y install docker
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, search-disabled-repos
No package docker available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@d8de679d27f2454 myuser]#
```

***Second Attempt***: Installing via `get.docker.com`

When running `curl https://get.docker.com | bash`, that doesn't work either

[image]

***Third Attempt***: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-docker-ce-on-rhel-7-linux/

Part of this article suggests running the following two commands:

```
sudo yum install -y https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
sudo yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
```

However, that doesn't work either:

```
# yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager

This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register.

https://download.docker.com/linux/rhel/7/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
Trying other mirror.
To address this issue please refer to the below knowledge base article 

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please open a ticket with Red Hat Support.



 One of the configured repositories failed (Docker CE Stable - x86_64),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=docker-ce-stable ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable docker-ce-stable
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=docker-ce-stable

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=docker-ce-stable.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from docker-ce-stable: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://download.docker.com/linux/rhel/7/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 - Not Found
```

Here's the output of my `cat /etc/os-release` command

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.9 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VARIANT="Server"
VARIANT_ID="server"
VERSION_ID="7.9"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.9:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It seems nearly impossible to install docker at this point.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 1):

Ran the following commands and this worked:

```
yum install -y https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-selinux-17.03.0.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
yum install -y https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-17.03.0.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 1):

Download latest version of these 3 packages from internet and

```
[root@test_hostame docker19.03_rpm]# ll
total 93904
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 30381608 Jan 20 18:19 containerd.io-1.3.9-3.1.el7.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 25519432 Jan 20 18:19 docker-ce-19.03.14-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 40247412 Jan 20 18:19 docker-ce-cli-19.03.14-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

run command in folder where only these 3 packages are present

```
yum localinstall *rpm
```

It is surely gonna work. If it doesnt, share your error.