# Docker pull fails during extraction with "lchown /usr/bin/sbd no such file or directory"

Tags: linux, docker

I've been battling trying to get Docker installed on RHEL7 and, now that I've been able to get it installed, I'm stuck just trying to do a simple `docker pull`.

I was able to finally get Docker installed using my proposed solution here [Issues installing Docker on RHEL 7 Linux Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66810139/issues-installing-docker-on-rhel-7-linux-server), but now during the extraction process, I get the following error:

```
latest: Pulling from [my-repo]
8657e219e309: Pull complete 
a8db9e62fad8: Extracting [==================================================>] 3.507 GB/3.507 GB
failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: lchown /usr/bin/sbd: no such file or directory
Unable to find image '[my-docker-repo]:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from [my-repo]
8657e219e309: Pull complete 
a8db9e62fad8: Extracting [==================================================>] 3.507 GB/3.507 GB
docker: failed to register layer: ApplyLayer exit status 1 stdout:  stderr: lchown /usr/bin/sbd: no such file or directory.
```

I'm not sure if this is related to the way I installed docker or if it's actually something else. I only installed docker using the following two commands:

```
yum install -y https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-selinux-17.03.0.ce-1.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
yum install -y https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7/x86_64/stable/Packages/docker-ce-17.03.0.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

I can run `docker` just fine and start the service, so not sure it's the installation that's the issue per se.

The only two issues I've found on the Internet that seems somewhat related to mine are these:

- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41803
- https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41821

However, neither one of these issues have solutions other than merged pull requests that apparently still aren't fixed in my case.

I've also visited https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#prerequisites and verified that the value shows 65,535 in my `/etc/subuid` and `/etc/subgid` values.

Still no luck.

Here's the output of my `docker info` command:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Build with BuildKit (Docker Inc., v0.5.1-docker)

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 0
 Server Version: 20.10.5
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: xfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:

  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 05f951a3781f4f2c1911b05e61c160e9c30eaa8e
 runc version: 12644e614e25b05da6fd08a38ffa0cfe1903fdec
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 3.10.0-1160.21.1.el7.x86_64
 Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.9 (Maipo)
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 7.349GiB
 Name: d8de679d27f2453
 ID: L43V:XEXI:6B6D:A3K4:KCI5:VQB7:MOG4:7TO5:QATR:5PM5:QT2Q:TTN5
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

Comment: What was your issue with https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/ ? You're installing a quite old version of docker (17.03), any specific reason for that? (The rootless doc you're referring is for more recent versions)

Comment: Yeah eventually I updated after realizing that the later versions were actually not at the top of the lists. When trying to use the centos URL, I kept running into an HTTP 404 error. I believe it's because the repo added `$basever` in the repo URLs, and mine resulted in 7Server (rather than 7), so it kept giving me 404 errors trying to access `https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/7Server/x86_64/stable/repodata/repomd.xml`

Comment: Can you add the result of `docker info` in your question?

Comment: You could edit the repo definition to force `7`

Comment: (you ran into https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/1111 and the solution is to replace $basever by 7 in the repo definition)

Comment: I tried editing the repo as well and was eventually able to get the correct docker installation going, but just having issues now with the `docker pull` process. I appreciate the reference though because I know I'll need it again on the next setup.

Comment: Ok. Can you adapt your question to your new setup and add the `docker info` output?

Comment: Updated @zigarn