# nvidia-docker : Got permission denied

Tags: linux, docker, gpu, nvidia, nvidia-docker

Docker newbie question here, so please be nice.

I know this might be asked before but I could not find anything related to nvidia-docker.
I completed the installation instructions on [the official guide](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker).

When I wanted to test Nvidia-docker:

`docker run --gpus all nvidia/cuda:10.0-base nvidia-smi`

I got this error:

```
(base) user@adminme:~$ docker run --gpus all --rm nvidia/cuda nvidia-smi
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/create: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue) here, but it felt a bit different for my case. I am very new to docker and still learning. let me know what you think?

here is some information about my remote Linux machine:

```
(base) user@adminme:~$ lspci | grep -i nvidia
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] (rev a1)
02:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

nvidia-smi command:

```
(base) user@adminme:~$ nvidia-smi
Sun May 31 01:12:25 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64.00    Driver Version: 440.64.00    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   33C    P8     9W / 215W |     17MiB /  8116MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      2545      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            15MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

docker-version :

```
(base) user@adminme:~$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.10, build 9424aeaee9
```

Comment: Do the solutions in the answer you linked to work for you?  How is your situation different?  (That should resolve the `/var/run/docker.sock: permission denied` problem.)

Comment: I am ashamed to say this was only sudo problem.

Comment: it is not just sudo, You can do as the answers said to avoid having to use sudo with docker

Answer (score 3):

The quick fix would be to run the container using `sudo`:

```
sudo docker run --gpus all nvidia/cuda:10.0-base nvidia-smi
```

If you want to run docker as non-root user then you need to add it to the docker group.

1. Create the docker group if it does not exist

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

2. Add your user to the docker group.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

3. Run the following command or Logout and login again and run (that doesn't work you may need to reboot your machine first)

```
newgrp docker
```

4. Check if docker can be run without root

```
docker run --gpus all nvidia/cuda:10.0-base nvidia-smi
```

> Ref:- https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what nischay goyal answered, sometimes after adding the user to the docker group you have to do

```
su - ${USER}
```

in order to log out and log back.