# How to run docker exec from php?

Tags: php, docker

Trying to run docker exec from php under Nginx I get the following error:

Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at `unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/konfetki_db_1/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`

This works from command line but it says `permission denied` while I'm trying to run from php under nginx with www-data instead of root.

Is there any way to run this?

Comment: The user which runs php does not have permissions to access the ``docker`` group, follow this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue but instead of using your own user, add the user where php runs. If you don't know it, ``<?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>`` will do the job.

Comment: If you can run any `docker` command at all, it's pretty easy to root the whole host.  I'd encourage you to rearchitect your application to not directly need to run `docker` commands, and avoid `docker exec` except for occasional debugging tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem by this:

```
Add docker group
$ sudo groupadd docker
Add your current user to docker group
$ sudo usermod -aG docker www-data
Switch session to docker group
$ newgrp - docker
Run an example to test
$ docker run hello-world
```