# Docker Permission Denied During Setup

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I am attempting to install and use docker for the first time. I have followed the guidelines provided in the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue) question:

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

which at this point returns (as expected):

```
groupadd: group 'docker' already exists
```

I then attempt to add the user to the group:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $wb_s2s
```

which only returns

```
Options:
  -b, --badnames                allow bad names
  -c, --comment COMMENT         new value of the GECOS field
  -d, --home HOME_DIR           new home directory for the user account
  -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE  set account expiration date to EXPIRE_DATE
  -f, --inactive INACTIVE       set password inactive after expiration
                                to INACTIVE
  -g, --gid GROUP               force use GROUP as new primary group
...
```

I then try to log out and lock back in and/or restart the computer/docker (I've tried everything). But when I run:

```
docker run hello-world
```

I get an error:

```
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at ... connect: permission denied. See 'docker run --help'.
```

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: The easiest way to add a user to a group is `sudo gpasswd -a <user> <group>`.  After you run it, make sure to *restart your login* to pick up the new group.    Use `groups` command to verify your groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add your user to the group, the docs meant literally `$USER` to refer to your user `wb_s2s` (which is a variable presented in your shell's environment for purposes like this)

adding `$` will make it a variable the shell interprets as an empty string

```sh
% echo $USER
ti7
% echo $ti7

% echo $whatever
```

You could use the `$USER` variable, or just remove the `$` from your attempt to add your user to the group

```
-sudo usermod -aG docker $wb_s2s
+sudo usermod -aG docker wb_s2s
```