# Act Not able to Use Docker API

Tags: docker, github-actions, docker-api, building-github-actions

I am trying to locally test github actions with the open-source [Act](https://github.com/nektos/act) utility.

> "Think globally, `act` locally"

I have copied the git hub repository for which i want to check github action and it does contains .github/workflow folders.
I run this command to run my github action.

```
act -v workflow_dispatch
```

It gives this error

```
DEBU[0000] Loading environment from /home/harshal/harshal/open-horizon.github.io/.env 
DEBU[0000] Loading secrets from /home/harshal/harshal/open-horizon.github.io/.secrets 
DEBU[0000] Loading workflows from '/home/harshal/harshal/open-horizon.github.io/.github/workflows' 
DEBU[0000] Loading workflows recursively                
DEBU[0000] Found workflow 'anaxdocscopy.yml' in '/home/harshal/harshal/open-horizon.github.io/.github/workflows/anaxdocscopy.yml' 
DEBU[0000] Found workflow 'link-snitch.yml' in '/home/harshal/harshal/open-horizon.github.io/.github/workflows/link-snitch.yml' 
DEBU[0000] Reading workflow '/home/harshal/harshal/open-horizon.github.io/.github/workflows/anaxdocscopy.yml' 
DEBU[0000] Correcting if statements '/home/harshal/harshal/open-horizon.github.io/.github/workflows/anaxdocscopy.yml' 
DEBU[0000] Reading workflow '/home/harshal/harshal/open-horizon.github.io/.github/workflows/link-snitch.yml' 
DEBU[0000] Correcting if statements '/home/harshal/harshal/open-horizon.github.io/.github/workflows/link-snitch.yml' 
DEBU[0000] Planning event: workflow_dispatch            
DEBU[0000] Loading slug from git directory '/home/harshal/harshal/open-horizon.github.io/.git' 
DEBU[0000] Found revision: a632f3efe8b7c29bc69794bcbf1f6ecd323467f0 
DEBU[0000] Loading revision from git directory '/home/harshal/harshal/open-horizon.github.io/.git' 
DEBU[0000] Found revision: a632f3efe8b7c29bc69794bcbf1f6ecd323467f0 
DEBU[0000] HEAD points to 'a632f3efe8b7c29bc69794bcbf1f6ecd323467f0' 
DEBU[0000] using github ref: refs/heads/master          
DEBU[0000] context env => map[ACT:true ISSUE_TEMPLATE:.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/check-broken-links.md URL:https://open-horizon.github.io/] 
DEBU[0000] context needs => map[]                       
[Link Snitch/build]   Start image=catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest
DEBU[0000] Loading slug from git directory '/home/harshal/harshal/open-horizon.github.io/.git' 
DEBU[0000] Found revision: a632f3efe8b7c29bc69794bcbf1f6ecd323467f0 
DEBU[0000] Loading revision from git directory '/home/harshal/harshal/open-horizon.github.io/.git' 
DEBU[0000] Found revision: a632f3efe8b7c29bc69794bcbf1f6ecd323467f0 
DEBU[0000] HEAD points to 'a632f3efe8b7c29bc69794bcbf1f6ecd323467f0' 
DEBU[0000] using github ref: refs/heads/master          
[Link Snitch/build]     docker pull catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest
DEBU[0000] FIXME: Got an status-code for which error does not match any expected type!!!: -1  module=api status_code=-1
DEBU[0000] Image exists? false                          
DEBU[0000] Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/json?filter=catthehacker%2Fubuntu%3Aact-latest": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
unable to determine if image already exists for image "catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest" () 
DEBU[0000] Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/json?filter=catthehacker%2Fubuntu%3Aact-latest": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
unable to determine if image already exists for image "catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest" () 
DEBU[0000] Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/json?filter=catthehacker%2Fubuntu%3Aact-latest": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
unable to determine if image already exists for image "catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest" () 
DEBU[0000] Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/json?filter=catthehacker%2Fubuntu%3Aact-latest": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
unable to determine if image already exists for image "catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest" () 
DEBU[0000] Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/json?filter=catthehacker%2Fubuntu%3Aact-latest": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
unable to determine if image already exists for image "catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest" () 
DEBU[0000] Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/json?filter=catthehacker%2Fubuntu%3Aact-latest": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
unable to determine if image already exists for image "catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest" () 
DEBU[0000] Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/json?filter=catthehacker%2Fubuntu%3Aact-latest": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
unable to determine if image already exists for image "catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest" () 
DEBU[0000] Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/json?filter=catthehacker%2Fubuntu%3Aact-latest": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
unable to determine if image already exists for image "catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest" () 
DEBU[0000] Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/json?filter=catthehacker%2Fubuntu%3Aact-latest": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
unable to determine if image already exists for image "catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest" () 
DEBU[0000] Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/json?filter=catthehacker%2Fubuntu%3Aact-latest": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
unable to determine if image already exists for image "catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest" () 
DEBU[0000] Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/json?filter=catthehacker%2Fubuntu%3Aact-latest": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
unable to determine if image already exists for image "catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest" () 
Error: unable to determine if image already exists for image "catthehacker/ubuntu:act-latest" (): Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/images/json?filter=catthehacker%2Fubuntu%3Aact-latest": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

I am new to docker and I literally don't know anything about it just that it creates containers(similar to OS) for running softwares. I tried searching on github issues for Act but could not find anything.
I installed docker with `sudo snap install docker` then I checked with `echo $?` which gave out `0` and `docker -v` which gave out `Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d28e`, so it seems like I do have running docker installed then still why it is giving this error.
And here is the github action/workflow file I wrote

```
name: Link Snitch

on:
  schedule:
    - cron:  '0 1 1 * *'
  workflow_dispatch:
  
 
env:
  URL: https://open-horizon.github.io/
  ISSUE_TEMPLATE: ".github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/check-broken-links.md"

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out master
        uses: actions/checkout@master
        with:
          fetch-depth: 1

      - name: Report broken links
        uses: victoriadrake/link-snitch@master
        with:
          Resursive urls: true
          URL: https://open-horizon.github.io/

        if: ${{ failure() }}
      - uses: JasonEtco/create-an-issue@v2.4.0
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          filename: ${{ env.ISSUE_TEMPLATE }}
        if: ${{ failure() }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a docker issue, because you want to run docker as a non-root user. You need to add docker to the docker group.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue) answer gives a detailed explanation on how to fix it. For me, running `sudo usermod -a -G docker $USER` and then rebooting worked.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the reason(s) for act to not work.

But when I ran the same command with root privileges it worked so I suppose it is trying to do something which requires root authorization. If someone can expand on this it will be helpful thank you.

Comment: How is the OP posting what they did to fix their problem not an answer to the question that they asked?

Comment: @novonimo There is a difference between Not An Answer (NAA) and an answer that isn't good. If you feel that this is the latter, you can downvote the answer, but recommending deletion is not the appropriate action here.