# docker commands without sudo user even after adding groupadd

Tags: docker, error-handling, permissions, sudo

even after adding `sudo groupadd docker` and `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER` , i cannot use docker commands without sudo

```
`Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
```

So I had to use "sudo". How can I get ignored sudo in docker commands

Comment: Did you log out and log in again, and/or run `newgrp docker`?  See the more complete recipes in [How to fix docker: Got permission denied issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue).

Answer (score 2):

After I installed Docker Desktop my Docker context was changed. Docker CLI commands are being forwarded to Docker Desktop instead of Docker Engine. If you have the same problem you can try

```
docker context ls
docker context use default
```

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Create a group called `docker` and add yourself to it using the commands

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Then you can run docker commands without using sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Giving more access to this file solves the problem, but it is not recommended it gives every local process and user unrestricted root access over the host!

```
chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
```

then you don't need  to use sudo but it's not recommended.

Comment: `chmod 0777` is almost always wrong -- you pretty much never want a file that's both world-writeable and executable.  For the Docker socket in particular you should make clear that "creates a security problem" is equivalent to "gives every local process and user unrestricted root access over the host"; that's a big enough problem that I wouldn't recommend it in an SO answer.

Comment: yeah you are right. my post was edited. regards @DavidMaze

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting docker.

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
sudo service docker restart
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have install docker desktop before than it created .docker directory

so just removing .docker directory it working

```
sudo rm -r  ~/.docker
```