# Getting Docker Dev Engine to work with VS Code

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, docker-machine

whenever I run the dev engine, I get the following error at the end of the install:

```
chown: invalid group: ‘root:docker’
WARNING: Could not change owner for docker socket in container : exit code 1
Docker socket permission set to allow in container docker
```

I am on macOS, so not sure if I need to create a docker group or not.

I have the following Dockerfile.devenv

```
FROM python:3.9-buster
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
USER root
WORKDIR /src
EXPOSE 8000
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash devenv
```

and no docker compose file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/dev-environments/specify/) when we are specifying Dockerfile, we need to make sure that we are using `vscode` user and included to `docker` group.

So i think your Dockerfile.devenv need to be updated. e.g:

```
FROM python:3.9-buster

WORKDIR /src
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# create vscode user then add to docker group
RUN useradd -s /bin/bash -m vscode \
 && groupadd docker \
 && usermod -aG docker vscode

USER vscode

EXPOSE 8000
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/docker-quickstart?view=vsmac-2019

It could be possible to run the service of Visual Studio by configurating the `dockerfile`:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY DockerDemo/DockerDemo.csproj DockerDemo/
RUN dotnet restore "DockerDemo/DockerDemo.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerDemo"
RUN dotnet build "DockerDemo.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerDemo.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerDemo.dll"]
```

So it could be possible to run your python environment within the environment for visual studio to run over macOS:

```
FROM python:3.9-buster
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
USER root
WORKDIR /src
EXPOSE 8000
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash devenv

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /src
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY DockerDemo/DockerDemo.csproj DockerDemo/
RUN dotnet restore "DockerDemo/DockerDemo.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/DockerDemo"
RUN dotnet build "DockerDemo.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "DockerDemo.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /src
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerDemo.dll"]
```

Comment: so I think this deploys a remote instance of vscode for a demo app that will run online. I am just trying to get the new Dev Environment (or really any containerized environment for python) running on VSCode locally. Once I have a docker container running, I can attach with the Remote Explorer. But when I try to do so, I get the above error message.

Normally I would just let it deploy normally, but it detects the 'main repository language' as jupyter notebook rather than python and so doesn't install the python dependencies.

Comment: That sounds that it can be fixed by creating a docker group first, probably this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue