# docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://0.0.0.0:1000. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker

I don't know who kill my docker daemon. After that, my docker stopped and I try to use some commands like
`service docker start`,
`systemctl restart docker`,
`systemctl daemon-reload`
is not useful.

So I uninstall docker and remove all docker env files. Then I reinstall docker, but when I use `docker ps`, the screen prints the error
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://0.0.0.0:1000. Is the docker daemon running?`

If use `sudo docker ps`, it works. So I try to add my account to sudo group then use `docker ps`, but get the same error.

My previous config file set the tcp for pycharm. But my new config file is the default.

Although I can add `sudo`  to use docker, I still want to figure it out.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature. The socket is owned by root. If there is a usergroup `docker` it is owned by this. So add your user to this group:

```
 sudo groupadd docker
 sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Logout and -in after that.

This group grants root-like rights, so be sure whom you trust..

Check also `env | grep DOCKER_HOST`, should be no value. If there is a value do `unset DOCKER_HOST`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I successfully solve the problem!

Comment: You're welcome. If an answer is helpful feel free to vote it up by clicking the arrow up and if it fully answers your question mark it as solution with the green tick. This helps others to see that it is solved and what to read first if they search for answers. This also makes a "Thank you" comment unnecessary and benefiting the user helped you with points.

Comment: If this turns out to be the actual issue, consider flagging it as a duplicate of [How to fix docker: Got permission denied issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue) rather than repeating its answers.

Comment: That's true but to welcome new members it is a quite harsh way. On next question I'd do that.. step by step :)