# Docker deamon don't work without "sudo". With sudo all services is working

Tags: docker, docker-compose

[image]

I trying this method, but docker deamon don't working and give me error on pic bottom.
Reboot and logout/login also doesn't help me.
With 'sudo' all nice working, but i can't use docker in vs-code and docker-desktop without non-root method.
!HELP!)

[image]

Comment: Is the daemon running? `systemctl status dockerd`

Comment: The daemon is not started. Run `sudo service docker start` (or the equivalent for the distribution in use).

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You say something about "this method", but you seem to have attached two images to the question in place of describing what you've done and what the error message is.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], including your actual source code, the commands you've run, and the error messages you get, all as plain text?  If this is just about running the Docker daemon also consider asking on a more appropriate site like [unix.se] and reviewing [How to fix docker: Got permission denied issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue).

Comment: @tkausl termial give: Unit dockerd.service could not be found.

Comment: Try using `docker` instead of `dockerd`, don't remember which name the service has.

Comment: @Turing85 after your command, i try `docker version` and get `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/kurama/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

Comment: Give  the daemon a moment to start up. If `sudo service docker status` shows the service in `Running` state, `docker version`, `docker ps`, ... should work.

Comment: @tkausl afrer `systemctl status docker` i get 
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-07-03 14:37:30 +03; 31min ago

Comment: @DavidMaze I want to use docker in rootless mode, but i can't do this, after commands from official docs. https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

Comment: @Turing85, `sudo version docker status` give me `Running`, but `docker version` and `docker ps` give me `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/kurama/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

Answer (score 4):

You have either set `DOCKER_HOST` or configured a context.

```
unset DOCKER_HOST
docker context use default
```

Comment: The explanation of why would require copy and pasting from a picture. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) and let me know when that's done so I can clarify this answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are in wsl and the interaction with the system is different, to get around that I used the `dockerd` command in other terminal

Comment: I try `sudo dockerd` and get 
`failed to start daemon: pid file found, ensure docker is not running or delete /var/run/docker.pid`

Comment: Are you sure you have a running Docker Desktop in the background ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your user in the docker group.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```