# How can I start Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I have installed Kubernetes and Minikube on [NixOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NixOS) 22.05. But I can't start Kubernetes:

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```

Output:

```
  minikube v1.25.2 on Nixos 22.05 (Quokka)
    ▪ MINIKUBE_WANTUPDATENOTIFICATION=false
✨  Using the docker driver based on user configuration

  Exiting due to PROVIDER_DOCKER_NEWGRP: "docker version --format -" exit status 1: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/version": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
  Suggestion: Add your user to the 'docker' group: 'sudo usermod -aG docker $USER && newgrp docker'
  Documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/
```

I followed the suggestion to add me to group docker:

```
sudo groupadd docker
```

Output:

```
[sudo] password for t:
groupadd: group 'docker' already exists
```

And:

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker
```

Output:

```
Adding user t to group docker
```

And:

```
newgrp docker
```

But it still doesn't work:

```
minikube start --driver=docker
```

Output:

```
  minikube v1.25.2 on Nixos 22.05 (Quokka)
    ▪ MINIKUBE_WANTUPDATENOTIFICATION=false
✨  Using the docker driver based on user configuration

  Exiting due to PROVIDER_DOCKER_NEWGRP: "docker version --format -" exit status 1: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/version": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
  Suggestion: Add your user to the 'docker' group: 'sudo usermod -aG docker $USER && newgrp docker'
  Documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/
```

What can I do?

Comment: are you able to run `docker run hello-world` with out `sudo`?

Comment: @Adiii no. I have to run docker commands with `sudo`. It may be because I started the daemon by `sudo dockerd &`. I couln't start the docker daemon without `sudo`, if I remember correctly.

Comment: and worth to consider `The problem was that I had to re-login after my user got the "docker" group. Everything works like a charm now!`

Comment: Does [How to fix docker: Got permission denied issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue) answer your question?

Comment: @ad why is it? It worked

Answer (score 0):

I tried running the same in a lot of ways.

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/rootless | sh
```

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-pluginmi
```

Nothing worked... But at last, running the below command worked...

```
docker context use default
```

This resolved my issue.