# Docker not working without sudo in Ubuntu, referencing .docker/desktop directory

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

On an Ubuntu 22.04 system, whenever I run any `docker` command, it prints out an error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/<username>/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

If I check with `systemctl status docker`, it shows that the Docker daemon is running, however.

Running `sudo docker ...` works, but I'd prefer to not prefix every Docker command with `sudo`.  I've tried many of the approaches in [How to fix docker: Got permission denied issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue), including adding my user to the `docker` group and relaxing the permissions on `/var/run/docker.sock`, but I still get this error.

What might be causing this?

Comment: did you find a solution, same here, docker build is giving an error: "error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `no usernames for https://index.docker.io/v1/`". But using `sudo` fixes it

Comment: this guide work for me, I just uninstall the docker and follow the digital ocean installation guide https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: I am not sure but this solution works for me

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you installed Docker Desktop first, then removed it and installed the Docker Engine, you may need to switch the Docker context with this command:

```bash
docker context use default
```

Because Docker Desktop switches context before startups and shutdowns not to interfere Docker Engine. So context might be kept incorrectly after removing Docker Desktop. A related article: https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-troubleshoot-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-errors/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is docker is running as root but vs code trying to connect in user.

I am also having this problem.
I solved this problem with install the **Docker Engine**

Delete the docker completely

```
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
```

Then install the Docker Engine
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/

Answer (score 2):

We should not install both the Docker engine and the Docker Desktop. If you install docker-engine alone the problem won't occur.