# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/alex/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Tags: docker, linux-mint-20

```
Linux Mint 20.3

docker --version
Docker version 23.0.1, build a5ee5b1
```

Here docker service status:

```
sudo systemctl status docker
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2023-03-16 11:10:40 EET; 4min 57s ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 1058896 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 18
     Memory: 47.0M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─1058896 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Mar 16 11:10:40 desktop dockerd[1058896]: time="2023-03-16T11:10:40.377886144+02:00" level=warning msg="Failed to allocate and map port 5432-5432: Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4>
Mar 16 11:10:40 desktop dockerd[1058896]: time="2023-03-16T11:10:40.457660980+02:00" level=error msg="4b414acd3c13853b905881b24703c1994938e086d30eb03f2437a6fc584fb229 cleanup: failed to del>
Mar 16 11:10:40 desktop dockerd[1058896]: time="2023-03-16T11:10:40.457678515+02:00" level=error msg="failed to start container" container=4b414acd3c13853b905881b24703c1994938e086d30eb03f24>
Mar 16 11:10:40 desktop dockerd[1058896]: time="2023-03-16T11:10:40.457744972+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Mar 16 11:10:40 desktop dockerd[1058896]: time="2023-03-16T11:10:40.488100344+02:00" level=warning msg="WARNING: No swap limit support"
Mar 16 11:10:40 desktop dockerd[1058896]: time="2023-03-16T11:10:40.488129877+02:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=bc3805a graphdriver=overlay2 version=23.0.1
Mar 16 11:10:40 desktop dockerd[1058896]: time="2023-03-16T11:10:40.488272612+02:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Mar 16 11:10:40 desktop dockerd[1058896]: time="2023-03-16T11:10:40.743944799+02:00" level=info msg="[core] [Server #7] Server created" module=grpc
Mar 16 11:10:40 desktop systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
Mar 16 11:10:40 desktop dockerd[1058896]: time="2023-03-16T11:10:40.747514473+02:00" level=info msg="API listen on /run/docker.sock"
```

Nice.
But when I try to run any docker command .e,g.

```
docker ps
```

I get error:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/alexe/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Comment: Does it work with `sudo docker ps`? In that case add your user to the docker group as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61026262/3083470)

Comment: @Taxel yes, it's help... but I want to start docker command without sudo. I try this https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-use  but it not help

Comment: This help me to run docker command without "sudo" : docker context use default

Comment: Did you install both Docker Desktop (which would use a socket in `$HOME`) and the standalone Docker Engine (managed by `systemctl`)?  Also see [Docker not working without sudo in Ubuntu 22.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73671461/docker-not-working-without-sudo-in-ubuntu-22-04).

Comment: @DavidMaze No, I'm not install docker desktop. I'm not need dockergui client. I work with docker only in terminal.