# How to change docker client's unix socket path?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

When I write `$ docker info` I get:

```
Client:
 Context:    desktop-linux
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.10.4)

Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/aotsaidera/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
errors pretty printing info
```

Docker daemon is active and is listening at /var/run/docker.sock:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
             └─options.conf
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2023-05-29 00:56:35 EEST; 7min ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 145146 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 12
     Memory: 20.2M
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─145146 /usr/bin/dockerd -H unix:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

май 29 00:56:34 aotsaideraPC dockerd[145146]: time="2023-05-29T00:56:34.750174683+03:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support CPU realtime scheduler"
май 29 00:56:34 aotsaideraPC dockerd[145146]: time="2023-05-29T00:56:34.750210015+03:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight"
май 29 00:56:34 aotsaideraPC dockerd[145146]: time="2023-05-29T00:56:34.750224946+03:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio weight_device"
май 29 00:56:34 aotsaideraPC dockerd[145146]: time="2023-05-29T00:56:34.750478719+03:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
май 29 00:56:35 aotsaideraPC dockerd[145146]: time="2023-05-29T00:56:35.005642810+03:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP address 172.17.0.0>
май 29 00:56:35 aotsaideraPC dockerd[145146]: time="2023-05-29T00:56:35.103761508+03:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
май 29 00:56:35 aotsaideraPC dockerd[145146]: time="2023-05-29T00:56:35.140482543+03:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit="20.10.21-0ubuntu1~20.04.2" graphdriver(s)=o>
май 29 00:56:35 aotsaideraPC dockerd[145146]: time="2023-05-29T00:56:35.140516773+03:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
май 29 00:56:35 aotsaideraPC systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
май 29 00:56:35 aotsaideraPC dockerd[145146]: time="2023-05-29T00:56:35.153669850+03:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
```

I tried changing the path by following the steps here:
https://geekflare.com/change-docker-sock-file-path/

When I entered `$ sudo gedit /etc/init/docker.conf` the file was empty, so I copied-pasted the one from the link and changed the path to /var/run/docker.sock but it didn't work and I left the file blank

Also tried pasting DOCKER_SOCKET = "/var/run/docker.sock" in

`/etc/init/docker.conf`  but it didn't help

I am successfully connected to the docker API using Intellij, but can't figure out how to fix the socket path in the terminal

Comment: Isn't it `DOCKER_HOST`?

Comment: If you are using Docker Desktop on your linux workstation, please read this article: 
https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/linuxfaqs/

>> While it’s possible to run both Docker Desktop and Docker Engine simultaneously, there may be situations where running both at the same time can cause issues...

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering why when I start Docker Desktop the `docker info` command stopped producing the error and connected, but when I shut it, the error reappeared.

Comment: If you have in fact installed Docker Desktop (the error message suggests that too), does [Docker not working without sudo in Ubuntu 22.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73671461/docker-not-working-without-sudo-in-ubuntu-22-04) describe your problem, and does its accepted answer (`docker context use default`) work for you?

Comment: Yes, it describes my problem and the accepted answer works for me. Sorry that I didn't find the linked thread and I am sorry for the duplicate question

Comment: same issue for me. docker stopped working after stopped docker desktop on ubuntu. i checked docker contexts by using `docker context ls` and saw there are 2 contexts. one for default docker engine and other for docker desktop. i switched from desktop context to default by using `docker context use default`. and my docker commands started working. THanks