# docker run hello-world docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/hexa/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Isthedocker daemon running

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, user-controls, admin

I have ubuntu 22.04 and have a Admin account and a normal user account. Have given normal user access for sudo docker commands by editing file (sudo visudo) have also
tried some of the commands
but still after running it as a normal user getting this error
docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/hexa/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
Your Help will be appreciated

sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

Comment: Have you logged out and back in as the normal user?

Comment: Docker Desktop runs a hidden Linux virtual machine, and you don't need it on a native-Linux host.  If you've installed both Docker Desktop and plain Docker, you might need to undo some of Desktop's settings.  Does [Docker not working without sudo in Ubuntu, referencing .docker/desktop directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73671461/docker-not-working-without-sudo-in-ubuntu-referencing-docker-desktop-directory) help?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding error text, need to check first is the docker demon started, if you're using docker desktop, the desktop application should be opened

I recommend you try to execute docker command from root first to exclude permission issue, if `docker ps` will work from root, let's check it from your user