# Docker Permission Denied on Windows?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, window

I was reading: [How to fix docker: Got permission denied issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue)

But what about windows? How can we fix this issue.

and what's the equivalent for:

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Please share the exact error message you see on Windows. I think I had something similar at some point, but it's not exactly the same, and the message is informative as to what the Windows-specific solution is.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, if you use windows, it's much better to install WSL ( windows subsystem linux ) for use Docker.
Because the windows core isn't stable with Docker.
keep me posted on progress
Bye