# Can't Acces Images I Created With "Sudo Su"

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.4:build-image
> (default) on project twitter-to-kafka-service: Execution default of
> goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.7.4:build-image
> failed: Connection to the Docker daemon at 'localhost' failed with
> error "[13] Permission denied"; ensure the Docker daemon is running
> and accessible: com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [13] Permission denied
> -> [Help 1]

I get the above error when I try to create an image using the spring-boot-maven-plugin. To solve the problem, I gave all privileges to the terminal with `sudo su` and the problem was solved.

However, I ran into a more interesting problem. Normal user cannot access the image created after typing `sudo su`. So in the Docker Desktop application, and when I type `docker images` in the terminal, I can't see the created images. Whenever I type `sudo su` and then `docker images` then I can view it. I don't want it to be this way either. Because it is easier to use Docker Desktop application.

```
docker images
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID   CREATED   SIZE


sudo su
[sudo] password for umut: 
root@umut-ThinkPad-E14-Gen-2:/home/umut# docker images
REPOSITORY                          TAG              IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
paketobuildpacks/run                base-cnb         320a67ab6606   2 weeks ago    87.8MB
tedex123/twitter-to-kafka-service   0.0.1-SNAPSHOT   a94cc13fed95   42 years ago   291MB
paketobuildpacks/builder            base             49d8ba727b2b   42 years ago   1.34GB
```

Comment: Why would you run `sudo su`? You either run `sudo <some executable>` to execute that as superuser, _or_ you use `su` to **s**ubstitute a **u**ser. You _never_ need to `sudo` the `su` command, the whole point is that you're asking the OS to change to a different user, which it will let you do as long as you provide the correct credentials for that user.

Comment: Do you mean I should use instead of ```sudo su``` then ```mvn install```, just use ```sudo mvn install```? Well, if you mean that I tried that but it's still the same.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to add your user to the docker group. I.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48957722/740553