# "Docker context ls" and "sudo docker context ls" don't have same setting options

Tags: linux, docker, desktop

I am a docker newbie. I just installed Docker and Docker Desktop as per offical instruction. Soon, I start to have problem like: the Docker Desktop does not show container. I think it's because I haven’t set the contexts same for with and without sudo privilege, according to this [post](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-desktop-in-ubuntu-not-showing-containers-those-are-build-with-sudo-privilege/129542).
But I don’t understand why I only have the “default” option for “sudo docker context ls”. Please help me on this. Many thanks!

OS:Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

screenshot

[image: 1]

Comment: Problem solved, by creating a context for root user using same DOCKER ENDPOINT as normal user. Following instruction here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/working-with-contexts/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `docker context` data is stored in the user's home directory.  When you use `sudo`, that changes users and home directories.  Without `sudo` it might look in `/home/yourname/.docker/contexts`, but when you switch to root with `sudo` it also changes home directories and looks in `/root/.docker/contexts`.

**You do not need Docker Desktop on native Linux.**  Installing Docker (what the Docker documentation now calls "Docker Engine") through your OS's package manager is sufficient.  If you are on a single-user system, you can [grant your ordinary user access to the Docker socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue), but be aware that it's all but trivial to use this access to root the entire host.

When you do uninstall Docker Desktop, there are [additional files in your home directory you need to remove](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/uninstall/)

```bash
rm -rf $HOME/.docker/desktop
$EDITOR $HOME/.docker/config.json
# and remove `credsStore` and `currentContext`
```

Once you've done this cleanup, you'll revert to Docker's default behavior of using the `$DOCKER_SOCK` environment variable, or without that, `/var/run/docker.sock`.  That system-global Docker socket file is the same regardless of which user you are, and it won't be affected by `sudo`.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and detailed explanation , David. I totally agree that "I do not need Docker Desktop on native Linux". But I just wan to test out the Desktop.
Problem solved, by creating a context for root user using same DOCKER ENDPOINT as normal user.

Comment: Could you explain how you create context for root user? I have gone through the official guideline. However, they did not clarify all the parameters /properties. Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need to create a context for the root user.  If you're using `sudo docker ...` to access the local machine, the default context behavior of accessing `/var/run/docker.sock` is right; if you're accessing a remote or VM-based Docker, you don't need `sudo` to do it.