# dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

Tags: docker, jenkins

I'm creating the image for Jenkins slave agent using `inbound-agent:jdk11-1.0` base image and installed Docker. But Docker is not working and I'm getting `ERROR: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/_ping": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`.

Please find the docker file for the image.

```
FROM jenkins-test-image-1.0
USER root
RUN apt-get -y update && \
 apt-get -y install \
   apt-transport-https \
   ca-certificates \
   curl \
   gnupg \
   lsb-release \
   software-properties-common
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
RUN apt-get -y update && \
 apt-get -y install \
   docker-ce \
   docker-ce-cli \
   containerd.io
RUN sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins

USER jenkins
```

Cans someone please help me.

I'm getting error for the Docker in Jenkins slave image.

Comment: Look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue)

Comment: I have already added Jenkins user to the docker group but in the container it's not happening. Could you please help me?

Comment: Please help with this. I'm running docker inside docker for Jenkins. I'm blocked with this error. I have tried every thing. it's not working.  Can some one please help me.

Comment: you can try to add `RUN sudo groupadd docker`, or `RUN sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`. also, how do you suppose this docker image will be able to access the outer `/var/run/docker.sock`? are you mounting this path inside the container?

Comment: RUN sudo groupadd docker command says docker group already exist.  This command is telling RUN sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock file not found.

Comment: how do you suppose this docker image will be able to access the outer /var/run/docker.sock? are you mounting this path inside the container? Yes, I'm mounting in the agent configuration

Comment: Please help me Arthur

Comment: Please help me how do i make it work?